# Java show .xls file twice as .xls and xlsx

Tags: java, xlsx, xls

I am trying to check folder which contains some `.xls` files, say

1. abc.xls
2. pqr.xls
3. xyz.xls

when I try to check files it shows files with both `.xls` and `.xlsx`

```
File folder = new File("PATH_TO_FOLDER");
File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
int count = fileList.length;
```

Here my folder contain only 3 files but `count` show 6 ?
`fileList` contain `[C:\test\abc.xls, C:\test\pqr.xls, C:\test\xyz.xls, C:\test\~$abc.xlsx, C:\test\~$pqr.xlsx, C:\test\~$xyz.xlsx]`

Why this happening, any help?

Comment: Those files are there, it is just that Windows hides them. Change the settings in Windows to show hidden files and you will see them.

Comment: Aren't those files starting with `~$` just hidden?

Comment: files starting with `~` are working files od Microsoft programs

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/is-in-front-of-my-file-name-open-it/54b19aed-4b16-4f96-a4bc-3a8c5476a164?auth=1

Comment: @ewramner first thing I have done is the same, checked with hidden files and no hidden file there. thats why I post question

Comment: Those are temporary lock files when the document is open by Ms office. They are hidden, do by default you cannot see them in the explorer. Nevertheless they are there.

Comment: This will create only when I open it by MS excel? But here I open only folder and checked list of files

Comment: Copy the three files to another folder and run the Java program with that path. You should see that there are only three files. The others are hidden by Windows but they are there.

Comment: you can use java.io.FilenameFilter so these files (their name start with ~) will not be add to fileList Array